# Adding limit to number of records in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap, pentaho-report-designer

I am using Pentaho Report Designer to generate some reports from my [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) cube. When I am preparing bar charts from data I want to restrict or limit the number of records displayed in the bar chart. Like if the user gives 1 and 10 as offset values then the bar chart should contain only these many records. How do I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You must do this in the query. The limit min/max values must be prompts which pass their value to the report, and you must code that logic in your SQL or MDX.

If your logic is too complex to do that I guess you could use a PDI datasource.

Note: that restriction in the data source is definitely the right place to do this; you definitely don't want to be applying such filters on the reporting side.